# Automatic URL Rewriting

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have created .htaccess file.

The original URL is:

http://example.com/folder/page.php?page=1&ipp=All&link=view_link

Redirected :

http://example.com/folder/page/1/All/link.html

Redirecting works correctly.But,Now the problem is ,

it will be redirected only if i give the rewrited URL manually.
But it should do automatically only.

**my requirement is if anybody type "page.php?page=1&ipp=All&link=view-link" then automatic convert /page/1/All/link.html**

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: my requirement is if anybody type "page.php?page=1&ipp=All&link=view-link" then automatic convert /page/1/All/link.html

Comment: It's usually the other way around. It's meaningless to convert from "ugly" urls to "pretty" urls, since the user has already typed them.

Comment: Do you need the same behavior if the URL is something like : page.php?page=2&ipp=None&link=view_link becomes page/2/None/link.html ? Or is it only for that one case with those specific values ?

Comment: I need the same behavior for all, not only for specific values

Answer (score 0):

I'm still very unclear on what you want based on your question, but I'll take a stab in the dark and assume you wanted to redirect the user from those "ugly" URLs to the cleaner format. If that's the case, this should work.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  ^[A-Z]+\s/[^/]+/.*\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)\.php /$1/%1 [C]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ipp=([^&]+)
RewriteRule .* $0/%1 [C]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} link=view(_|-)([^&]+)
RewriteRule .* $0/%2.html? [R=301,L]
```

Which will redirect users who go to `folder/page.php?page=1&ipp=All&link=view-link` (Or is it `/folder/page.php?page=1&ipp=All&link=view_link`? Your question has both, so I let it accept either) to `folder/page/1/All/link.html`, regardless of what any of the components of that original URL are.